# 22.04 LTS sound from different sources interrupting each other

Tags: sound, notification, system

On my fresh 22.04 install on a Dell Precision 5570 notebook I'm experiencing sound problems. When I e.g. play a movie on netflix and a system notification sound is played, the sound from the movie is interrupted. In fact, sometimes the video stutters, too, for the duration of the system sound being played back.

This also happens for other applications, e.g. playing a game via Wine (or also natively), listening to MP3, ...

Also, this seems to happen regardless of which output device I'm using. I've tried sound via HDMI and also via the Line-Out in my Thunderbolt docking station (Dell WD19TB).

Any idea on how to fix this? It seems to be somehow related to the new hardware since on my old machine (Dell Precision 4570) this never happened with 22.04 LTS.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

You're not the only one with this problem and my guess is Pulseaudio causing this issue.
For years I've been recording NOAA satellite images without any problem until Pulseaudio became the 'new' default on Ubuntu.
[Raw NOAA image while receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWSRf.jpg)
After purging Pulseaudio the problems of breaking up disapeared.
It seems that Pulseaudio is randomly scanning all audio inputs for 'availability' like testing if something plugged in. A real pain in the bum for me.
Having just Alsa sound installed does make the soundcards harder to manage though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).